# For what range does this floor function scale to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I have $\lfloor\frac{X}{(2y+1)^2}\rfloor = k$ where $X$ and $k$ are known. For what values of $y$ will this hold true?

edit: all are positive integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac{X}{(2y+1)^2}\right\rfloor = k \iff k \le \frac{X}{(2y+1)^2} < k+1$

You know that $(2y+1)^2 \ge 0$, so we may multiply it on both sides.  Moreover, since you have $k \ge 0$ and $X \ge 0$, this yields:

$\frac{X}{k+1} < (2y+1)^2 \le \frac{X}{k}$

I believe you can do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve $$(2y+1)^2k\leq X<(2y+1)^2(k+1)$$ for $y$.